# Boost.Python - How do you raise a KeyError?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I have a Boost.Python function that I need to return a string or raise an exception if one does not exist. The code roughly looks like this (but isn't 100% exact)

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace
{
    std::string getFoo(std::string const& key)
    {
        boost::optional<std::string> value {_SOMETHING_ELSE.get(key)};

        if (value)
        {
            return value.get();
        }

        // Need to throw the exception here
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_KeyError, "This didn't work");
        throw NotSure {"asfd"};  // Or return ""; ?
    }
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(exactMatch)
{
    boost::python::def("getFoo", &getFoo);
}
```

I see that Boost.Python already maps some built-in stdexcept exceptions to their reasonable Python counterparts. For example:

C++ -> Python

- `std::out_of_range` -> `IndexError`
- `std::runtime_error` -> `RuntimeError`
- `std::invalid_argument` -> `ValueError`

However I don't see an exception for that for Python.

### What I've tried

In the `// Need to throw the exception here` section, I tried using

```cpp
PyErr_SetString(PyExc_KeyError, "This didn't work");
return "";
```

Doing that raises a SystemError, not a KeyError. Example:

```
KeyError: 'This didn\'t work'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 123, in test_function
    getFoo()
SystemError: <Boost.Python.function object at 0x20b4590> returned a result with an error set
```

The KeyError was obscured by the fact that I both return a C++ object and raise a Python exception at the same, which is a reasonable error. But if you try to replace the return with a C++ exception, Boost.Python just uses that:

```cpp
PyErr_SetString(PyExc_KeyError, "This didn't work");
throw std::runtime_error {"This didn't work"};
```

Using that will raise a `RuntimeError`, not a `KeyError` as expected.

And if you omit the return / throw entirely and just end with `PyErr_SetString`, C++ will segmentation fault, so that's not an option.

### Final Notes

I'm not interested in creating a custom Python exception class and really would rather stick to Python's built-in exceptions. I just don't know how to achieve a `KeyError`, in this case. If Boost.Python doesn't map to `KeyError` out of the box, I would settle for mapping a custom class to `KeyError`, even if that process is a bit manual to set up. But I'm not sure how to do that as well. Either way, I would appreciate some advice. Thank you!

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/high_level_components/boost_python_exception_translato.html

Comment: @AlanBirtles Exactly what I needed, thank you! For anyone reading, the steps were 1. Define a custom C++ class (optional) 2. Add `register_exception_translator<TheClassYouWantHere>(&translate);` and then 3. Define `translate` as a function that raises `PyErr_SetString(PyExc_KeyError, e.what());`

It's easy once you know how